# ¿Cómo puedo animar el texto en Ionic para que cuando no entra en la pantalla vaya desplazandose de derecha a izquierda?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic

Como se muestra en la imagen, hay parte del texto en el que solo se ven unos puntos suspensivos (...) Me gustaría que para que se viera completamente fuese desplazándose de derecha a izquierda el texto completo y quitar esos puntos suspensivos. Lo quiero solo en el caso de que no se vea completo, no en pantallas en las que si se vea bien por ser mas anchas.

[image: Adjunto imagen de mi problema]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Lee [ask]: ¿podrías adjuntar un [repro] de lo que tienes hasta el momento?

Comment: Hola... ¿Has probado ionic-marquee?